# How can I display the response on the table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am building an app which makes a request to an API and displays the response in a table view. I am using using decodable. I am able to see the response when I print it. But I am not able to display it to my table view. Thought my logic was right. How can I display the response to the table view. Thanks for all replies and explanations.

Model

```
struct Businesses: Decodable {

    let businesses : [Business]

}

struct categorie : Decodable{

    let title: String

}

struct Business: Decodable {

    let name: String

    let categories: [categorie]

    let rating: Double

    let price: String?

}
```

View controller

```
var businesses = [Business]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let business = businesses[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: 
    indexPath) as! DiscoverTableViewCell

    cell.restaurantNameLabel.text = business.name

    cell.restaurantLocationLabel.text = business.name

    cell.typeLabel.text = business.name

    return cell



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return businesses.count

}



func network (){

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

    if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {

        print(response)

    } else {

        print("error")

    }

    guard let data = data else {return}

    // print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "???")

    do {

        let businessesJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(Businesses.self, from: data)

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        print(businessesJSON)

        }

        } catch {

                print("Error parsing JSON: \(error)")

        }

    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly (with readable indenting).

Comment: You need to do `self.businesses = businessesJSON`

Answer (score 0):

when you print the businessesJSON what output you are getting ?

The table view is running in the main thread you supposed to call the tableview.reloadData in the main thread using

`DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}`

Comment: This what I get on the console :                                                                          [FoodPin.Business(name: "Fog Harbor Fish House", categories: [FoodPin.categorie(title: "Seafood"), FoodPin.categorie(title: "Bars")], rating: 4.0, price: Optional("$$")), FoodPin.Business(name: "The House", categories: [FoodPin.categorie(title: "Asian Fusion")], rating: 4.5, price: Optional("$$$"))]

Comment: that means JSON parsing working fine.. you suppose to call the tableview.reloaddata in the main thread by this line.                                                        
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

Comment: I tried it, it's working. I need to go learn about the main thread and everything. Was completely confuse could not understand why my tableview was empty .

Comment: you supposed need to read about threads, then you will get to know what all these. so you got the result now ?

Comment: if you wanna read something more about this just go through this https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/understanding-threads-in-ios-5b8d7ab16f09

Answer (score 0):

Before `self.tableView.reloadData()` add: `self.businesses = businessesJSON`

Example:

```
let businessesJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(Businesses.self, from: data)
self.businesses = businessesJSON
self.tableView.reloadData()
```